typing in a number to a cell (say 5) to then merge those 5 cells
Merging multiple lines if one range selected
I have created a small hotel template for reservations
I have created dates and a range of selections
How or what formula, if any, can I use to
when I enter
number of nights
guest name
booking source
villa size
cost per night
total cost

cells all merge automatically so I don't have to merge them each time one by one?
Then what formula do I put in to auto add the cost per night to the number of nights?

Re: Merging multiple lines if one range selected

What software is this question about, exactly?
